# Jackson convert blank String into null

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am having JSON String like

```
{"firstName":"ABC", "middleName":"", "lastName":"XYX"}
```

I am converting this string into `JsonNode`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<JsonNode>() {});
```

It works perfectly but I want to convert middleName value from `""` to `null`, so that `JsonNode` should be like

```
{"firstName":"ABC", "middleName":null, "lastName":"XYX"}
```

I have added one serializer

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(String.class, new StdSerializer<String>(String.class) {

            @Override
            public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
                    throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
                if("".equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
                    jgen.writeNull();
                }else{
                    jgen.writeString(value);
                }

            }
        });

        mapper.registerModule(module);
    mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<JsonNode>() {});
```

But it is returning same String as a `JsonNode`. What I am missing actually?

Comment: Wouldn't you actually want 
{"firstName":"ABC", "middleName":, "lastName":"XYX"}
then?

Comment: I have to convert it into bean later on. So i want null only

Answer (score 0):

Jackson will give you null for other objects, but for Strings, it will give empty String.

But you can use a Custom JsonDeserializer to do this:

```
class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
        if (node.asText().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return node.toString();
    }

}
```